# Faster scroll speed for vncviewer when in full screen

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, fedora, xorg, vnc

I've started `x11vnc` on a machine with two screen and am using `vncviewer` from a single screen machine to connect to it. That is, **the local window is smaller than the remote screen**. In fullscreen mode (`F8`->`Fullcreen`), you can move the mouse to the edge of the screen to scroll around. This is incredibly slow for me (taking a whopping ~20 seconds or so just to view the other screen).

From [TightVNC docs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/xtightvncviewer.1.html), there are these options:

> **`bumpScrollTime`**, **`bumpScrollPixels`**
>                 When in full screen mode and the VNC desktop is bigger than  the
>                 X display, scrolling happens whenever the mouse hits the edge of
>                 the screen. The maximum speed of scrolling  is  bumpScrollPixels
>                 pixels  every  bumpScrollTime  milliseconds. The actual speed of
>                 scrolling will be slower than this, of course, depending on  how
>                 fast your machine is.  Default 20 pixels every 25 milliseconds.

This sounds like the options I want to set, but for the current `vncviewer` in Fedora21 (and I assume many other distros), TigerVNC, which is a [fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TigerVNC#cite_note-1) of TightVNC. **How can I make scrolling in fullscreen faster?** Perhaps there are options in `~/.vnc/config` or as part of the command line I can set.

Update: [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/tigervnc/feature-request-tracker/63/) looks related, but I can't find anything that fixes the problem.

I can't find a link to the [TigerVNC](http://tigervnc.org/) docs I see via `man vncviewer`, so here it is...

```
vncviewer(1)                                                                            Virtual Network Computing                                                                            vncviewer(1)



NAME
       vncviewer - VNC viewer for X

SYNOPSIS
       vncviewer [options] [host][:display#]
       vncviewer [options] [host][::port]
       vncviewer [options] -listen [port]

DESCRIPTION
       vncviewer is a viewer (client) for Virtual Network Computing.  This manual page documents version 4 for the X window system.

       If you run the viewer with no arguments it will prompt you for a VNC server to connect to.  Alternatively, specify the VNC server as an argument, e.g.:

              vncviewer snoopy:2

       where  'snoopy' is the name of the machine, and '2' is the display number of the VNC server on that machine.  Either the machine name or display number can be omitted.  So for example ":1" means
       display number 1 on the same machine, and "snoopy" means "snoopy:0" i.e. display 0 on machine "snoopy".

       If the VNC server is successfully contacted, you will be prompted for a password to authenticate you.  If the password is correct, a window will appear showing the desktop of the VNC server.


AUTOMATIC PROTOCOL SELECTION
       The viewer tests the speed of the connection to the server and chooses the encoding and pixel format (color level) appropriately.  This makes it much easier to use than previous  versions  where
       the user had to specify arcane command line arguments.

       The  viewer normally starts out assuming the link is slow, using the encoding with the best compression.  If it turns out that the link is fast enough it switches to an encoding which compresses
       less but is faster to generate, thus improving the interactive feel.

       The viewer normally starts in full-color mode, but switches to low-color mode if the bandwidth is insufficient. However, this only occurs when communicating with servers supporting protocol  3.8
       or newer, since many old servers does not support color mode changes safely.

       Automatic selection can be turned off by setting the AutoSelect parameter to false, or from the options dialog.


POPUP MENU
       The  viewer has a popup menu containing entries which perform various actions.  It is usually brought up by pressing F8, but this can be configured with the MenuKey parameter.  Actions which the
       popup menu can perform include:

         * switching in and out of full-screen mode

         * quitting the viewer

         * generating key events, e.g. sending ctrl-alt-del

         * accessing the options dialog and various other dialogs

       By default, key presses in the popup menu get sent to the VNC server and dismiss the popup.  So to get an F8 through to the VNC server simply press it twice.


FULL SCREEN MODE
       A full-screen mode is supported.  This is particularly useful when connecting to a remote screen which is the same size as your local one. If the remote screen is bigger, you can scroll by bump‐
       ing the mouse against the edge of the screen.

       Unfortunately this mode doesn't work completely with all window managers, since it breaks the X window management conventions.


OPTIONS (PARAMETERS)
       You  can  get a list of parameters by giving -h as a command-line option to vncviewer.  Parameters can be turned on with -param or off with -param=0.  Parameters which take a value can be speci‐
       fied as -param value.  Other valid forms are param=value -param=value --param=value.  Parameter names are case-insensitive.

       Many of the parameters can also be set graphically via the options dialog box.  This can be accessed from the popup menu or from the "Connection details" dialog box.


       -display Xdisplay
              Specifies the X display on which the VNC viewer window should appear.


       -geometry geometry
              Standard X position and sizing specification.


       -listen [port]
              Causes vncviewer to listen on the given port (default 5500) for reverse connections from a VNC server.  WinVNC supports reverse connections initiated  using  the  'Add  New  Client'  menu
              option or the '-connect' command-line option.  Xvnc supports reverse connections with a helper program called vncconfig.


       -passwd password-file, -PasswordFile password-file
              If you are on a filesystem which gives you access to the password file used by the server, you can specify it here to avoid typing it in.  It will usually be "~/.vnc/passwd".


       -DotWhenNoCursor
              Show the dot cursor when the server sends an invisible cursor.


       -PointerEventInterval
              Time in milliseconds to rate-limit successive pointer events.


       -ImprovedHextile
              Try harder to compress data (default).


       -QualityLevel level
              JPEG quality level (default is 8).


       -NoJPEG
              Disable lossy JPEG compression in Tight encoding.


       CompressLevel level
              Use specified compression level (default is 2).


       CustomCompressLevel level
              Use custom compression level. Default is CompressLevel is specified.


       -SendPrimary
              Send the primary selection and cut buffer to the server as well as the clipboard selection (default).


       -SendClipboard
              Send clipboard changes to the server (default).


       -AcceptClipboard
              Accept clipboard changes from the server (default).


       -Shared
              When  you make a connection to a VNC server, all other existing connections are normally closed.  This option requests that they be left open, allowing you to share the desktop with some‐
              one already using it.


       -ViewOnly
              Specifies that no keyboard or mouse events should be sent to the server.  Useful if you want to view a desktop without interfering; often needs to be combined with -Shared.


       -Maximize
              Maximize viewer window.


       -FullScreen
              Start in full-screen mode.


       -FullScreenAllMonitors
              Enable full screen over all monitors (default).


       -FullscreenSystemKeys
              Pass special keys directly to the server in full-screen mode.


       -RemoteResize
              Dynamically resize the remote desktop size as the size of the local client window changes (default).


       -DesktopSize widthxheight
              Instead of keeping the existing remote screen size, the client will attempt to switch to the specified since when connecting. If the server does not  support  the  SetDesktopSize  message
              then the screen will retain the original size.


       -AutoSelect
              Use automatic selection of encoding and pixel format (default is on).  Normally the viewer tests the speed of the connection to the server and chooses the encoding and pixel format appro‐
              priately.  Turn it off with -AutoSelect=0.


       -FullColor, -FullColour
              Tells the VNC server to send full-color pixels in the best format for this display.  This is default.


       -LowColorLevel, -LowColourLevel level
              Selects the reduced color level to use on slow links.  level can range from 0 to 2, 0 meaning 8 colors, 1 meaning 64 colors (the default), 2 meaning 256  colors.  Note  that  decision  if
              reduced color level is used is made by vncviewer. If you would like to force vncviewer to use reduced color level use -AutoSelect=0 parameter.


       -PreferredEncoding encoding
              This option specifies the preferred encoding to use from one of "Tight", "ZRLE", "hextile" or "raw".


       -UseLocalCursor
              Render the mouse cursor locally if the server supports it (default is on).  This can make the interactive performance feel much better over slow links.


       -WMDecorationWidth w, -WMDecorationHeight h
              The total width and height taken up by window manager decorations.  This is used to calculate the maximum size of the VNC viewer window.  Default is width 6, height 24.


       -log logname:dest:level
              Configures the debug log settings.  dest can currently be stderr or stdout, and level is between 0 and 100, 100 meaning most verbose output.  logname is usually * meaning all, but you can
              target a specific source file if you know the name of its "LogWriter".  Default is *:stderr:30.


       -MenuKey keysym-name
              This option specifies the key which brings up the popup menu.  The key is specified as an X11 keysym name (these  can  be  obtained  by  removing  the  XK_  prefix  from  the  entries  in
              "/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h"  -  the  currently implemented list is: F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10, F11, F12, Pause, Print, Scroll_Lock, Escape, Insert, Delete, Home, Page_Up,
              Page_Down).  Default is F8.


       -via gateway
              Automatically create encrypted TCP tunnel to the gateway machine before connection, connect to the host through that tunnel (TigerVNC-specific). By default, this option invokes SSH  local
              port  forwarding,  assuming that SSH client binary can be accessed as /usr/bin/ssh. Note that when using the -via option, the host machine name should be specified as known to the gateway
              machine, e.g.  "localhost" denotes the gateway, not the machine where  vncviewer  was  launched.  The  environment  variable  VNC_VIA_CMD  can  override  the  default  tunnel  command  of
              /usr/bin/ssh -f -L "$L":"$H":"$R" "$G" sleep 20.   The tunnel command is executed with the environment variables L, H, R, and G taken the values of the local port number, the remote host,
              the port number on the remote host, and the gateway machine respectively.


       -ZlibLevel level
              Zlib compression level.


       -x509crl file
              X509 CRL file


       -x509ca file
              X509 CA certificate


       -SecurityTypes types
              Specify which security scheme to use.


SEE ALSO
       Xvnc(1), vncpasswd(1), vncconfig(1), vncserver(1)
       http://www.tigervnc.org


AUTHOR
       Tristan Richardson, RealVNC Ltd.

       VNC was originally developed by the RealVNC team while at Olivetti Research Ltd / AT&T Laboratories Cambridge.  TightVNC additions were implemented by Constantin  Kaplinsky.  Many  other  people
       participated in development, testing and support.



TigerVNC                                                                                       05 May 2004                                                                                   vncviewer(1)
```

And the relevant bit is:

> A full-screen mode is supported.  This is particularly useful when connecting to a remote screen which is the same size as your local one. If the remote screen is bigger, you can scroll by bumping the mouse against the edge of the screen.

but no mention of configuring it.

If a dev ever sees this, rather than a constant scroll speed why not scroll by the amount you move the mouse past the edge of the screen??

Comment: OK, at the very least can you comment on why this is a bad question or doesn't belong on this site?